# Constants for State Names

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a list of state abbreviations from an API:

['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', ...]

I have a list of the full state names that I would like to display in my view.
I want to create some sort of constant for these values as follows:

```
.value('states', {
    'AL': 'Alabama',
    'AK': 'Alaska',
    'AZ': 'Arizona',
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to access these states values in an ng-repeat?

e.g:

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.states" theme="bootstrap" search-enabled="false">
  <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="stateProv as stateProv in stateList">
    <div ng-bind-html="stateProv"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Every expression in the view is evaluated on the scope of the current controller. So just put the list in the scope:

```
myApp.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, states) {
    $scope.stateList = states;
    ...
});
```